# How do I send email to multiple users from a single email form? laravel 8

Tags: laravel

In my application, I can send an email to a single user!
but I want to send to multiple users at the same time from a single form!

**My class**

```
    class SendEvent extends Mailable {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;
        public $data;

        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct($data) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }

        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build() {
            return $this->markdown('emails.eventEmail');
        }
    }
```

This is the `send()` function below.

**My controller**

```
    class EmailController extends Controller {
        public function send(Request $request) {
            $homeUrl = url('/');
            $eventId = $request->get('event_id');
            $eventTitle = $request->get('event_title');

            $eventUrl = $homeUrl.'/'.'events/'.$eventId.'/'.$eventTitle;

            $data = array(
                'your_name'=>$request->get('your_name'),
                'your_email'=>$request->get('your_email'),
                'friend_name'=>$request->get('friend_name'),
                'eventUrl'=>$eventUrl
            );

            $emailTo = $request->get('friend_email');   
            Mail::to($emailTo)->send(new SendEvent($data));
            return redirect()->back()->with('message','Event link sent to '.$emailTo);
        }
    }
```

Here in the recipient address form, I can only add just one address!

**My form in the model**

```
    <form action="{{route('mail')}}" method="POST">@csrf
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="{{$event->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="event_title" value="{{$event->title}}">

            <div class="form-goup">
                <label>Your name * </label>
                <input type="text" name="your_name" class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-goup">
                <label>Your email *</label>
                <input type="email" name="your_email" class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-goup">
                <label>Person name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="friend_name" class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-goup">
                <label>Person email *</label>
                <input type="email" name="friend_email" class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mail this event</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How do I get my code to send to more than one email address from my form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it by making $friend_name an array

```
<input type="email" name="friend_email[]" class="form-control" required="">
```

and then you may add a js function to append this input for more emails
something like that

```
 $( "#form" ).append( "<input type="email" name="friend_email[]" class="form-control" 
    required="">
   " );
```

and that's it.
The friend_email will be passed to the `Mail`  as an array and every email in it will receive the mail